# Reorganize multiple variables based on date variable in R

Tags: r, date, organization, longitudinal, reorganize

If I have a dataset that has scores from the same measure collected at different time points, how can I organize those dates/times so they represents a timepoint after a certain date? Is this possible to do in R or would it be easier for me to do this in another program?

I have a dataset that currently looks like this:

```
id  date        score1_date score1  score2_date score2  score3_date score3
101 1/6/2020    1/1/2020    20      1/8/2020    18      1/15/2020   16
102 2/27/2020   2/14/2020   16      2/21/2020   16      2/28/2020   10
103 1/10/2020   1/7/2020    30      1/14/2020   25      1/21/2020   20
104 3/5/2020    3/6/2020    40      3/13/2020   42      3/20/2020   40
```

I want to find the closest [score#_date] to [date] and identify that as [time1] and then have everything that follows as [time2], [time3], etc.

Here is the code for that above table:

```
structure(list(id = c(101, 102, 103, 104), date = structure(c(18267, 
18319, 18271, 18326), class = "Date"), score1_date = structure(c(18262, 
18306, 18268, 18327), class = "Date"), score1 = c(20, 16, 30, 
40), score2_date = structure(c(18269, 18313, 18275, 18334), class = "Date"), 
    score2 = c(18, 16, 25, 42), score3_date = structure(c(18276, 
    18320, 18282, 18341), class = "Date"), score3 = c(16, 10, 
    20, 40)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

So I would eventually want the dataset to have variables that look something like this:

```
id  date        time1_date  time1_score time2_date  time2_score time3_date  time3_score
101 1/6/2020    1/8/2020    18          1/15/2020   16          NA          NA
102 2/27/2020   2/28/2020   10          NA          NA          NA          NA
103 1/10/2020   1/7/2020    30          1/14/2020   25          1/21/2020   20
104 3/5/2020    3/6/2020    40          3/13/2020   42          3/20/2020   40
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` functions you can do :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  #Rename date column to base_date
  rename(base_date = date) %>%
  #Rename score1, score2 etc to score1_value, score2_value etc
  rename_with(~paste0(., '_value'), matches('^score\\d+$')) %>%
  #get the data in long format with date and value as two columns
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('score'), 
               names_to = c('score', '.value'), 
               names_sep = '_') %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  #Keep only those date where the date is greater than closest date
  filter(date >= date[which.min(abs(date  - base_date))]) %>%
  #Arrange the data
  arrange(id, date) %>%
  #Create new column name
  mutate(score = paste0('time', row_number())) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  #Get the data in wide format
  pivot_wider(names_from = score, values_from = c(date, value)) %>%
  #Arrange the columns
  select(id, base_date, order(suppressWarnings(readr::parse_number(names(.)))))

#    id base_date  date_time1 value_time1 date_time2 value_time2 date_time3 value_time3
#  <dbl> <date>     <date>           <dbl> <date>           <dbl> <date>           <dbl>
#1   101 2020-01-06 2020-01-08          18 2020-01-15          16 NA                  NA
#2   102 2020-02-27 2020-02-28          10 NA                  NA NA                  NA
#3   103 2020-01-10 2020-01-07          30 2020-01-14          25 2020-01-21          20
#4   104 2020-03-05 2020-03-06          40 2020-03-13          42 2020-03-20          40
```

Comment: the expected outcome by OP, doesn't matches with yours in `id == 103`.  Please re-check

Comment: I think you are right, I missed that. Thanks, Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a slightly different approach that includes reordering of the final columns:

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  rename(target = date) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),as.character)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(id,target),names_pattern = "score([0-9]+)_?(.*)", names_to = c("num","variable")) %>%
  mutate(variable = case_when(variable == "" ~ "score", TRUE ~ variable)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("id","num","target"),names_from = variable, values_from = "value") %>%
  filter(date >= target) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(date) %>%
  mutate(new_num = row_number()) %>%
  select(id,target,new_num,date,score) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c("id","target"), names_from = new_num, values_from = c("date","score")) %>%
  group_by(id,target) %>%
  select(paste0(rep(c("date","score"),times = ncol(.)/2),"_",rep(1:3,each = ncol(.)/3)))
#Adding missing grouping variables: `id`, `target`
## A tibble: 4 x 8
## Groups:   id, target [4]
#  id    target     date_1     score_1 date_2     score_2 date_3     score_3
#  <chr> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>   <chr>      <chr>   <chr>      <chr>  
#1 101   2020-01-06 2020-01-08 18      2020-01-15 16      NA         NA     
#2 103   2020-01-10 2020-01-14 25      2020-01-21 20      NA         NA     
#3 102   2020-02-27 2020-02-28 10      NA         NA      NA         NA     
#4 104   2020-03-05 2020-03-06 40      2020-03-13 42      2020-03-20 40
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest a different strategy to filter out rows, using `cummin` and `abs` functions as under

```
df %>%
  rename(base_date = date) %>%
  rename_with(~paste0(., '_value'), matches('^score\\d+$')) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('score'), 
               names_to = c('score', '.value'), 
               names_sep = '_') %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(d = abs(as.numeric(difftime(base_date, date, units = "days"))),
         score = str_remove(score, "\\d$")) %>%
  filter(cumsum(cummin(d) == min(d)) != 0) %>%
  mutate(score = paste0(score, row_number())) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(id,base_date), names_from = score, values_from = c(date, value))

# A tibble: 4 x 8
# Groups:   id [4]
     id base_date  date_score1 date_score2 date_score3 value_score1 value_score2 value_score3
  <dbl> <date>     <date>      <date>      <date>             <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1   101 2020-01-06 2020-01-08  2020-01-15  NA                    18           16           NA
2   102 2020-02-27 2020-02-28  NA          NA                    10           NA           NA
3   103 2020-01-10 2020-01-07  2020-01-14  2020-01-21            30           25           20
4   104 2020-03-05 2020-03-06  2020-03-13  2020-03-20            40           42           40
```

`pivot_wider` has a column rearrangement [issue #839](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/issues/839) still open on Github, so either you can manually rearrange the columns or adopt the strategy proposed by Ian in last line of his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66978882/2884859)

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful.